# strerror_r identifier not found - png++ and Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, png, libpng

I am running a project on vs 2013 that requires the png++ library. After downloading and including it in my project I am getting an error in the `error.hpp` file.

```
368 IntelliSense: identifier "strerror_r" is undefined  c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\png++\error.hpp  108 32  spsstereo
Error   55  error C3861: 'strerror_r': identifier not found c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\png++\error.hpp  108 1   spsstereo
Error   154 error C3861: 'strerror_r': identifier not found c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\png++\error.hpp  108 1   spsstereo
Error   313 error C3861: 'strerror_r': identifier not found c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\png++\error.hpp  108 1   spsstereo
```

Answer (score 3):

Close to the top of `error.hpp`, change

```
#ifdef __STDC_LIB_EXT1__
```

to

```
#if defined(__STDC_LIB_EXT1__) || defined(_WIN32)
```